# How to get exported value of svelte component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, flowbite-svelte

The library `flowbite-svelte` has component `Popover` with `open` property. The property changing by click on button. In order to control external event listener (no in example) I need to know current value of `open` property. How to get it?

I tried to use `open=` and `bind:open=`, but buth `undefined` when button clicked.

[Online REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/91e2e6012a104bc39ad521cad1c4bde2?version=4.2.1)

```
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
import { Popover } from 'flowbite-svelte'

let popover
let isOpen

onMount(() => {
  popover.$on('show', () => {
    console.log(popover.open) // undefined
    console.log(isOpen) // undefined
  })
})
</script>

<button>Click</button>

<Popover
  <!-- open={isOpen} or bind:open={isOpen} -->
  bind:this={popover}
  trigger="click">
    Some content
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution via debugging. When `show` event occurs, callback has `this` with popover instance. Inside `this.$$.ctx` stored values by index from `this.$$.props`.

```
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
import { Popover } from 'flowbite-svelte'

let popover

onMount(() => {
  popover.$on('show', onPopoverOpenChanged)
})

function onPopoverOpenChanged() {
  let indexPropOpen = this.$$.props.open
  let isOpen = this.$$.ctx[indexPropOpen]
  if (isOpen) {
    
  } else {
    
  }
}
</script>

<button>Click</button>

<Popover
  bind:this={popover}
  trigger="click">
    Some content
</Popover>
```

Comment: In case it was not obvious, this relies on internal behavior that could change without notice.

Answer (score 1):

There [is no property for that](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/components/popover#Component_data), and there also is only a `show` event, no event for closing.

That being the case, there currently is no proper way of getting the state. You could maybe query the DOM, but this functionality should be part of the component.

Maybe open an issue if there is none already.